# c++ unit testing using fake boost::filesystem

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-filesystem

Currently I am working on a module that reads a directory looking for files with specific pattern in filenames. I am using boost::filesystem.
 I've been thinking that it would be good idea to have something that mimics filesystem without directly interacting with it, unless it's production code.

I found this link:
http://user.xmission.com/~legalize/boost.test/libs/test/doc/html/test/guide/testing_file_io.html
Looked great, but when I tried to use this code. I found that calling next() could throw if there's no more files. I'm not sure if code like this is considered a good practice:

```
    std::vector<std::string> results;
    try
    {
        std::string s = directory_scanner.next;
        if (s.find("some_pattern")
        results.push_back(s);
    }
catch(...){hmm now what?}
```

This looked like a generic solution, so I was interested with this. 
But maybe it's completely wrong now in 2016 :)

Maybe it's better to have a virtual method 'get_interesting_files' in directory scanner and inject it to an object that needs to be unit tested?